# shortcode not return any thing in Gutnburg

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I need to create a shortcode in a plugin, when a person gets to install my plugin can he use shortcode inside the plugin :

that's my code plugin is working 100%
but when I call to shortcode [splite] nothing returned

```
class aligoPlugin
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // hooks
        add_action( 'init',  array($this,'register_shortcodes') );
    }

    // activate
    public function activate()
    {
        $this->splite_article();
        // add_shortcode('splite', 'splite_article');
        // flush rewrite rules
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    // functions
    function register_shortcodes(){
        add_shortcode('splite', 'splite_article');
    }

    // shortCodes
    function splite_article()
    {
        $content = "hhhhh";
        echo $content;
    }
}
if (class_exists('aligoPlugin'))
    $aligo = new aligoPlugin();

// activation
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($aligo,'activate'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 major bugs here

### Problem 1: Your shortcode registration is invalid

You should be seeing lots of messages about this in your PHP error log

```php
add_shortcode('splite', 'splite_article');
```

There is no function named `splite_article`, there's a class function but the code didn't tell it to use it. So instead of calling your shortcode function, it generates a PHP error message and puts it in the log.

`add_shortcode` expects a PHP callable value, so `splite_article` is equivalent to `splite_article()`, but you need `$this->splite_article()`.

So instead use the appropriate callable `[ $this, 'splite_article' ]`

### Problem 2: Shortcodes do not echo

```php
echo $content;
```

That's not how shortcodes work, shortcode callbacks do not echo HTML, they return it. This shortcode will be breaking a lot of things as a result of this.

Luckily the solution is simple, `return` the shortcodes content instead.

Comment: yeah thank you really helpful

Comment: i just need for my shortcode to return ( <!--nextpage--> ) to tell Wordpress using pagination , but short code just return ( <!--nextpage--> ) and nothing happen

Comment: i got the result i need thank's @Tom